# Windows 7 Clock On/Off shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, clock

Apologies if I'm asking this in the wrong place etc. I've love to have a keyboard shortcut to turn off and on clock in windows 7. I've done a good bit of research and I can't find anything. Would anyone be able to help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Which clock?  The clock in the system tray?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'turn it off'? As in *hide* it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no built-in shortcut for hiding the clock.

But you can create one using [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html):

> NirCmd is a small command-line utility that allows you to do some useful tasks without displaying any user interface. By running NirCmd with simple command-line option, you can write and delete values and keys in the Registry, write values into INI file, dial to your internet account or connect to a VPN network, restart windows or shut down the computer, create shortcut to a file, change the created/modified date of a file, change your display settings, turn off your monitor, open the door of your CD-ROM drive, and more...

#### Steps

1. Download and install NirCmd.
2. Create a shortcut on the desktop (or anywhere else) that executes the following command:

   ```
    nircmd.exe win child class "Shell_TrayWnd" hide class "TrayClockWClass"
   ```
3. Save the shortcut and edit it (right click → **Properties**) to assign a keyboard shortcut to it.